# Misstep With Discriminant and equations writable as quadratic form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I missed a step in my equation and would like to know what i'm doing wrong.

I have the following equation:
${x^{4} -  {\color{red}15} x^{2} +  {\color{red}54}  = 0}$

Now, we let ${y = x^2}$
We can now rewrite our equation to...
$${y^2-15y+54}$$
We can also factor it into 2 binomials.. $${(y-6)(y-9)}$$

Here is where I am stuck however, My answer after that is
$$\sqrt{-6},\sqrt{6},\sqrt{-9}.\sqrt{9}$$

This certianly is not the answer as I am provided 4 options, here is one just for reference (May not be the correct solution) $$x=3,-3, \sqrt{y}, -\sqrt{6} $$

Thanks!

Comment: $(x^2-9)=(x-3)(x+3)$ as difference of squares would apply, no? Similary, $(x^2-6)=(x - \sqrt 6)(x+\sqrt 6)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factorization is incorrect. It should be
$$
y^2−15y+54 = (y-6)(y-9)
$$

Note that *your* factorization yields this:
$$
(y-18)(y+3)=y^2−15y{\color{red}-}54 
$$

Comment: Silly me, I missed that the values didn't add up. Thank you for the correction. However, i'm unsure how I come to an answer as mine still doesn't match anything. Currently i'm sitting at $\sqrt{3},=\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6},\sqrt{-6}$